# how do overwrite changed columns of one file from another file in perl

Tags: perl

I have two files like below:

file1:

```
column1 column2
---------------
h1      0
h2      0
h3      0
h4      0
```

file2:

```
column1 column2
---------------
h1      1
h2      1
```

I want to compare these two files and write a new file, which will look like below:

```
column1 column2
---------------
h1      1
h2      1
h3      0
h4      0
```

Whats the best way to do it, since reading the files to array and looping over wouldn't exactly get the file3 output.

Comment: I had to add a little more complexity, that if file 1 has "h1 0 h2 1 h3 1 h4 1" and file2 has "h1 1" output should look like, h1 1 h2 0 h3 0 h4 0 (apparently all the second fields for file 2 except for matching first field from file2 should be made 0), can this be acheived?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first field on each line in each file is a "key" that indicates whether a line in `file1.txt` should be replaced by a line in `file2.txt` , you could try:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my %lines;
my @lines;
my $fn = 'file1.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $key, @rest ) = split " ", $line;
    push @{ $lines{$key} }, $. ;
    push @lines, $line;
}
close $fh;
my $fn2 = 'file2.txt';
open ( my $fh2, '<', $fn2 ) or die "Could not open file '$fn2': $!";
while( my $line = <$fh2> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $key, @rest ) = split " ", $line;
    if ( exists $lines{$key} ) {
        for my $line_no (@{ $lines{$key} }) {
            $lines[$line_no -1] = $line;
        }
    }
}
close $fh2;

say for @lines;
```

**Output**:

```
h1 1
h2 1
h3 0
h4 0
```

**Edit**: To also set all lines which is not updated by `file2.txt` to "$key 0":

```
[...]
my %used_keys;
while( my $line = <$fh2> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $key, @rest ) = split " ", $line;
    if ( exists $lines{$key} ) {
        for my $line_no (@{ $lines{$key} }) {
            $lines[$line_no -1] = $line;
        }
        $used_keys{$key} = 1;
    }
}
close $fh2;
delete @lines{ keys %used_keys };
for my $key (keys %lines) {
    for my $line_no (@{ $lines{$key} }) {
        $lines[$line_no -1] = "$key 0";
    }
}
[...]
```

Comment: I had to add a little more complexity, that if file 1 has "h1 0 h2 1 h3 1 h4 1" and file2 has "h1 1" output should look like, h1 1 h2 0 h3 0 h4 0 (apparently all the second fields for file 2 except for matching first field from file2 should be made 0), can this be acheived?

Comment: Yes, that can be done. See my updated answer for an approach.

Comment: The above code gives and error at line: delete %lines{$_} for keys %used_keys; and the error is "delete argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element or slice " !

Comment: @NewUser Maybe you could send me the files you are using? Then I will have a look at it.

Comment: sure, will send an email in a while!